# DAO test case getting failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

DAO test cases getting failed due to below error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.flapdoodle.embed.process.config.RuntimeConfig

we are using spring boot 2.7.3 version , Spring data mongoDB :3.4.2, MongoDB :4.2,
de.flaodoodle.embeded.mongo-2.2.0, de.flaodoodle.embeded.process-2.1.2

Please help for the same

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
```

It will disable auto configuration as that causes issues. You can use your own configuration in this case.